# Active Record Relation Joins - 3 main tables, 2 join tables

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, data-modeling, scoping

### The setup

I have a data model with 3 major tables (users, links, topics) with 2 join tables (link_saves and link_topics). My models:

User

```
has_many :link_saves, :class_name => 'LinkSave', :foreign_key => 'user_id'
has_many :links, :through => :link_saves
```

LinkSave

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :link
```

Link

```
has_many :link_saves, :class_name => 'LinkSave', :foreign_key => 'link_id'
has_many :users, :through => :link_saves

has_many :link_topics, :inverse_of => :link
has_many :topics, :through => :link_topics
```

LinkTopic

```
belongs_to :link
belongs_to :topic
```

Topic

```
has_many :link_topics
has_many :links, :through => :link_topics
```

### The Question

I want to be able to find a list of all the topics a user has saved links for.  I would like to be able to do `@user.topics` and have it hop across all 5 tables from user all the way to topics.  More importantly, I want this to return an ActiveRecord relation so that I can scope/sort/page the list of user topics further so this would NOT work:

```
## app/models/user.rb

def topics
  links.collect(&:topics)
end
```

Am I going down the wrong path?  Is there a way to do this through active record without having to write all the custom SQL?  Help please!

### Possible Answers (Update)

#### Using multiple `has_many :through`s to make all the hops.  This works, but can't be best practice, right?

```
## app/models/user.rb
has_many :link_saves, :class_name => 'LinkSave', :foreign_key => 'user_id'
has_many :links, :through => :link_saves
has_many :link_topics, :through => :links, :uniq => true
has_many :topics, :through => :link_topics, :uniq => true
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is called a 'nested' has_many through, basically going from A to B to C.

In Rails 3.1 this functionality is now supported 
http://www.warmroom.com/yesterdays/2011/08/30/rails-3-1-nested-associations/

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html (search for 'Nested')

The example they have is a bit simpler than what you have, but I think it should be enough for you to get some ideas.

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments, :through => :posts
  has_many :commenters, :through => :comments
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commenter
end

@author = Author.first
@author.commenters # => People who commented on posts written by the author
```

Prior to Rails 3.1 there was a plugin
'https://github.com/releod/nested_has_many_through'

Comment: This did end up working, I put the final solution that worked in my particular case above.  Would upvote but Stack doesn't think I have a good enough reputation yet!

Comment: That's crazy that you can't upvote an answer to your own question. Hopefully someone else will.